# Problem with Axios PUT and GET request, sometimes work well, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-cli

I'm using Axios to fetch data from a server, I'm trying to do a PUT request and I need to get data info from 3 tables in order to fill the form, when I do the PUT it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, but when I open the browser terminal to debug the problem, the PUT request always works, also I notice that another component without nested GET requests always works fine, but I can't fetch the data from the server if those GET requests aren't nested.

Here is my script code, I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this.

```
  <template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="margin:40px;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);">
      <div class="row">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/usuarios">Usuarios</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/roles">Roles</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a v-bind:href="rol_url">{{rol_name}}</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Editar Rol</li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <button onclick="window.history.back();" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#003e1e;border-color:#003e1e;">
                <font-awesome-icon icon="arrow-left" size="lg"></font-awesome-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-5 align-self-center">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="rolName">Nombre del rol:</label>
                  <input v-model="rol_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="rolName" aria-describedby="rolName" placeholder="Nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="rolModules">Modulos del rol:</label>
                  <multiselect v-model="rol_mod" :options="modules" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="true" :clear-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Seleccione los modulos" label="name" track-by="modulo" :preselect-first="false">
                  </multiselect>
                </div>
                <div v-for='(module, index) in rol_mod' :key='index' class="form-group">
                  <label for="rolModules">Permisos de {{module.name}}</label>
                  <multiselect v-model="module.permisos" :options="permits" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="true" :clear-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Seleccione los permisos del modulo" label="name" track-by="_id" :preselect-first="false">
                  </multiselect>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="rolStates">Estado del rol:</label>
                  <multiselect v-model="rol_state" :options="states" track-by="name" label="name" :searchable="false" :close-on-select="true" :show-labels="true" :placeholder="rol_state_get">
                  </multiselect>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="permitDescription">Descripción:</label>
                  <textarea v-model="rol_description" class="form-control" aria-label="permitDescription"
                  placeholder="Descripción" :rows="6" :max-rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-4 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="submit()" style="background:#003e1e;border-color:#003e1e;">
                      <font-awesome-icon icon="save" size="lg"></font-awesome-icon>
                      Guardar
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#003e1e;border-color:#003e1e;" v-bind:href="rol_url">
                      <font-awesome-icon icon="times-circle" size="lg"></font-awesome-icon>
                      Cancelar
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
const axios = require('axios');
var API_IP = process.env.VUE_APP_API_IP

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data () {
    return {
      rol_auditoria: {},
      modules: [],
      permits: [],
      rol_name: "",
      rol_state: "",
      rol_state_get: "",
      rol_description: '',
      states: [
        { name: "Activo", activo: "true" },
        { name: "Inactivo", activo: "false" }
      ],
      rol_mod: [],
      rol_url: ""
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
    .get(API_IP+'/rol/'+this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.rol_auditoria = response.data.data.auditoria;
      this.rol_name = response.data.data.nombre;
      this.rol_state = response.data.data.activo;
      response.data.data.activo? this.rol_state_get="Activo" : this.rol_state_get="Inactivo";
      this.rol_description = response.data.data.descripcion
      this.rol_id = response.data.data._id
      this.rol_url = "/roles/"+response.data.data._id

      for (var k in response.data.data.modulos){
        var mod_info = {}
        console.log(response.data.data.modulos[k].modulo.nombre);
        mod_info["_id"] = response.data.data.modulos[k]._id
        mod_info["modulo"] = { "_id" : response.data.data.modulos[k].modulo._id }
        mod_info["name"] = response.data.data.modulos[k].modulo.nombre
        var mod_per = []
        for (var j in response.data.data.modulos[k].permisos){
          var perms = {}
          perms["_id"] = response.data.data.modulos[k].permisos[j]._id
          perms["name"] = response.data.data.modulos[k].permisos[j].nombre
          mod_per.push(perms)
        }
        mod_info["permisos"] = mod_per
        this.rol_mod.push(mod_info)
      }

      axios
      .get(API_IP+"/module/")
      .then(response => {
        for(var k in response.data.data){
          var mod = {}
          mod["modulo"] = { "_id" : response.data.data[k]._id }
          mod["name"] = response.data.data[k].nombre;
          this.modules.push(mod);
        }
        axios
        .get(API_IP+"/permit/")
        .then(response => {
          for(var k in response.data.data){
            var per = {}
            per["name"] = response.data.data[k].nombre;
            per["_id"] = response.data.data[k]._id;
            this.permits.push(per);
          }
        });
      });

    })

  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
      axios
      .put(API_IP+"/rol/"+this.$route.params.id, {
        auditoria: this.rol_auditoria,
        activo: this.rol_state.activo,
        _id: this.rol_id,
        nombre: this.rol_name,
        descripcion: this.rol_description,
        modulos: this.rol_mod
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      this.$router.push({ name: 'showrol', params: { id: this.rol_id} });
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: When you say the PUT request doesn't always work. In what way does it fail? Does the request come back with an error from the server, or is the request returning successfully?

Comment: Please add catch (es) to all your axios calls, theres probably a bad request coming back from the GETs. The code itself seems fine

Comment: When something's not working, you should always explain what does it mean. Simply "not working" cannot help anyone help you. The request either fails, which means you can send us the error, or it doesn't which means there's a problem in your front end logic. Please provide more information so people can help you :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying this thread.
When I say that it doesn't work is because when I do the request, it doesn't change anything in that register in the database, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, I can't try to debug because I'm not getting any bad response from the server (even when I print the response in the view I get a 200), and when I open the console it always do the update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long shot without having information from the console output and the actual info or errors being returned from the GET requests, but I noticed a lot of "this" use on your code.

1. You are double nesting axios calls, which are async. "this" tends to be hard to debug in javascript, even if youre using arrow functions which should be relatively safe.

Please try to add:

```
let self = this;
```

Before you start your GET requests, and use "self" instead of "this" inside your promises.

2. This may be obvious, but I dont see you calling this.submit() anywhere in your code. Where inside the GET callbacks are you calling SUBMIT for the PUT request?

Comment: Even if axio was changing the scope (which it doesn't), Steven is constantly using arrow functions, so the scope (this) is never changed. Good thinking though! :) I would advise you to ask questions / provide suggestions in the comments and answer only if you have a real clue what's not working. Otherwise people might downvote your answer and therefore it will just clutter the whole platform. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, I call submit() in the HTML part in the component, specifically in a button.
About the nested GET requests, I don't if it's correct to do it in that way but is the only way that works for me, if I don't nest that two requests it doesn't fetch me any data from the server.